# Ubuntu package libzstd1 still old version

Tags: ubuntu, update, packages

After upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 i have a package problem.

When i try to install the package default-libmysqlclient-dev:

```
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

it fails with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libzstd-dev : Depends: libzstd1 (= 1.4.8+dfsg-2build2) but 1.4.8+dfsg-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when i list my installed packagers it look like the old 20.10 version of libzstd1 is still installed.

```
libzstd1/now 1.4.8+dfsg-2+ubuntu20.10.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 [installed,local]
libzstd1/hirsute 1.4.8+dfsg-2build2 i386
```

How can i upgrade libzstd1 to the new version without breaking the system?